# T-SQL Pivot multiple columns duplicates results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with aggregated data that I would like to pivot. Here is a sample of the data:

```
Unit#   EffectiveDay    RequestCount    ResponseCount
5       1               0               0
5       2               8               8
5       3               4               4
5       4               4               4
5       5               2               2
5       6               0               0
5       7               2               2
6       1               0               0
6       2               0               0
6       3               0               0
6       4               0               0
6       5               0               0
6       6               0               0
6       7               0               0
```

I can successfully pivot the RequestCount column, but when I add the ResponseCount column it's as if the rows increased exponentially. Instead of two rows (one for each unit#), I get 14.

```
select  *
from    (
            select  Unit#
                    ,concat('Request', EffectiveDay) AS RequestDay
                    ,RequestCount
                    ,concat('Response', EffectiveDay) As ResponseDay
                    ,ResponseCount
            from    #tmpLogPayConnexion
        ) as P
pivot   (
            sum(RequestCount)
            for RequestDay in ([Request1], [Request2], [Request3], [Request4], [Request5], [Request6], [Request7])
        ) as pvtRequest
pivot   (
            sum(ResponseCount)
            for ResponseDay in ([Response1], [Response2], [Response3], [Response4], [Response5], [Response6], [Response7])
        ) as pvtResponse
```

I know this is possible, but I am stumped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a time for a crosstab, or conditional aggregation.

```
select [Unit#]
    , Request1 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 1 then RequestCount end)
    , Request2 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 2 then RequestCount end)
    , Request3 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 3 then RequestCount end)
    , Request4 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 4 then RequestCount end)
    , Request5 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 5 then RequestCount end)
    , Request6 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 6 then RequestCount end)
    , Request7 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 7 then RequestCount end)
    , Response1 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 1 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response2 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 2 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response3 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 3 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response4 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 4 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response5 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 5 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response6 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 6 then ResponseCount end)
    , Response7 = max(case when EffectiveDay = 7 then ResponseCount end)
from #tmpLogPayConnexion
group by [Unit#]
order by [Unit#]
```

Comment: Sean, this definitely works and gets me what I need.  In your opinion, a pivot is not possible (just trying to learn)?

Comment: I prefer to use a crosstab when I can instead of a pivot. The syntax is far less obtuse for me and they are a bit more flexible. One real challenge with a pivot is multiple sets like you are trying to do. It isn't as true as it used to be but the crosstab has a very slight performance bonus over pivot also. But that doesn't really come into play unless you are talking a million rows or more.